# Apache Samza aggregation rules for missing expected events in rolling time-period

Tags: real-time, distributed-computing, stream-processing, apache-samza

My use-case is to identify entities from which expected events have not been received after X amount of time in real-time.

For example:
If we have received PaymentInitiated event at time T but didn't receive either of PaymentFailed / PaymentAborted / PaymentSucedded by T+X, then raise a trigger saying PaymentStuck along with details of PaymentIntitiated event.

How can I model such use-cases in Apache Samza as it is rolling time period X on each event, rather than fixed time interval.

Thanks, Harish

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any native support for this in Samza, but I can imagine a work-around that uses WindowableTask.

```java
public class PaymentEvent implements Comparable<PaymentEvent> {
    // if current time > timestamp, payment is stuck
    public long timestamp; 
    // we want a corresponding PaymentFailed... event with the same id
    public long interactionId; 
    // PaymentRequest, PaymentAborted, PaymentSucceeded...
    public enum type;
    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PaymentEvent o){
        return timestamp - o.timestamp;
    }
}
```

Now in your process method you would have something like:

```java
PriorityQueue<PaymentEvent> pqueue;
Map<Long, PaymentEvent> responses;

public void process(...) {
    PaymentEvent e = new PaymentEvent(envelope.getMessage());
    if (e.enum == PAYMENT_REQUEST) {
        pqueue.add(e);
    } else {
        responses.put(e.interactionId, e);
    }
}
```

And finally during your window you would pop off from the priority queue everything with `timestamp > current time` and check if there is a corresponding event in the Map.

```java
public void window(...) {
    while(pqueue.peek().timestamp <= currentTime) {
        if (!map.containsKey(pqueue.poll().interactionId) {
            // send the trigger via the collector
        } 
    }
}
```

Then lastly you would set the window time in your configuration to however long you wanted to poll. The config is `task.window.ms`.